# MATLAB plot part of surface

Tags: matlab, plot

Say I have the following script:

```
u = -5:.2:5;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(u, u);
Z = cos(X).*cos(Y).*exp(-sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2)/4);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Is there anyway that I can make MatLab plot only parts of the surface?  Say, for instance, I just want to plot a single point, or a single grid, what can I do?  I thought perhaps to plot a single point I could use:

```
surf(X(1,1), Y(1,1), Z(1,1))
```

But then I get the error message:

```
??? Error using ==> surf at 78
Data dimensions must agree.
```

I would really appreciate some input/help here. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try what you tried, I get the following:

> > > surf(X(1,1),Y(1,1),Z(1,1))
> > >       Error using surf (line 75) Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

So the problem is that you can't do just a point or line using `surf`, you'd have to use a different function.  But you **can** select subregions

```
>> ii=1:5;
>> jj=1:20;
>> surf(X(ii,jj),Y(ii,jj),Z(ii,jj))
```

Another way to do it is to use NaNs as a mask.

```
>> mask = ones(size(X));
>> mask(1:20, 20:end) = nan;
>> surf(X.*mask, Y.*mask, Z.*mask)
```

This will make the parts where NANs are present not be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

To display only a single point, you might like the function scatter3, designed for point clouds.

```
scatter3(X(1,1), Y(1,1), Z(1,1))
```

Of course, it also works on vectors of X,Y,Z points.  You can also directly specify point size and color for each point.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Really appreciate your input.