# Dissimilar results to the surface plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, surface

```
>> x=0:0.001:720;
>> y=sind(x);
>> z=cosd(x);
>> surf(x,y,z);
```

I want to plot a surface using the above code i.e. x in X-axis, y is Y-axis, and z in Z-axis.
I also programmed a FORTRAN code for the following purpose, created a csv file, and plotted it in origin. I am getting a result as this:

[image: FORTRAN Result]

However, in MATLAB, I am getting a similar idea when using:-

```
>> plot3(x,y,z)
```

as in this image:

[image: MATLAB Result]

but it's not a surface (for obvious reasons).

When using the `surf` command, I am also getting an error saying:

> `Z` must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

What could be the possible problem with my code?

Comment: Related post: [How can I plot a function with two variables in octave or matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061)

Comment: If `y` and `z` both are functions of just `x`, can you explain why your plot changes by `y`?

Comment: I don't know much about MATLAB, but I wanted similar results, x in X-axis, y in Y-axis, & z in Z-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) requires `Z` to be a matrix. This is fixed easily with functions like [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) (also useful is [`griddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html)).

Using [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) makes using [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) very accessible.

But both `Z` and `Y` are just functions of `X` so I'm unable to explain why your plot `Z`-value would change with both `X` and `Y`.  From the analytical (mathematical) equations you've listed, the `Z`-value should be constant in the `Y`-dimension.

```
stepsize = 1;     % use 10 for cleaner look
x = 0:stepsize:720;
y = sind(x);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = cosd(X);

surf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image: Surface plot]

Notice that the contour lines are straight & parallel in the `Y` dimension (using `surfc(X,Y,Z)`).
[image: Surface plot with contours shown beneath]

Another method is to loop through elements of `x` (indexed by `i`) and `y` (indexed by `j`) where both `x` and `y` (vectors) to calculate `Z(i,j)` where `Z` is a matrix. Due to default assignment for rows & columns, this method requires transposing the `Z` matrix such as `surf(X,Y,Z.')`.

---

**Related Posts:**
[How can I plot a function with two variables in octave or matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061)
[MATLAB plot part of surface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10856298/8239061)

Comment: Ok, I got it. Can you please tell how to fill solid colour to that plot3(x,y,z) image?

Comment: You mean like with the `surf` command?  What is missing from the posted answer? I'm not following what you're wanting.

Comment: Actually I got what you meant. I even went through some meshgrid command. Thanks.

Comment: Great! You can click the check mark to let the community know this solved your issue.  If there's still remaining issues with this, feel free to comment.

Comment: Sure, but alas, currently I am below 15 reputation.